# Where to put script references for widgets (partial page)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Working on MVC5 asp.net website.

I have a "dashboard" page that allows the user to place pre-defined "widgets" on the page. These widgets are simply MVC 5 partial pages (Razor). I really wanted each widget to be "self-contained" so all references, scripts, etc... are within the widget's cshtml file. BUT, the main "dashboard" page also needs certain references to jQuery, bootstrap, etc...

Of course, doing this, I could encounter conflicts, duplicate references (one from main page, one from widget), etc....

Question: What is the preferred method for this scenario? Should references like jQuery and bootstrap be JUST on the main "dashboard" page? What about javascript or jQuery code that is in the widget itself? Should this remain in the widget? If so, will I encounter the issue where it doesn't have jQuery defined (because it's in the parent page), etc...?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated?

Thanks!

**** UPDATE ****

TO further clarify: If I put the scripts, references, etc (specific to the widget) at the bottom of the widget, then when the partial page is rendered on the main page, the scripts, etc.. are not rendered at the bottom of the main page. This causes my code to act funny because of the order that things are rendered. This is one reason I ask this question. Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script code and references that are global to the application , that are used everywhere and that are not specific to a widget in the most outer page.

What i would do, is i would bundle all my script references in one place and add that bundle link to the dashboard page, this makes your code cleaner and your page will have less external references thus a better client side performance.

Comment: Thanks @Bsayej. But, for example, let's say I have a widget that is a drill-down bar chart, lot's of jQuery code, etc.... Should the related jQuery, css, etc... go in the widget itself, minus the global jQuery/bootstrap references, for example? I read somewhere that it's cleaner not to have any scripting/references in partial pages. What's best practice?